# How can I add a PDF document to my Flows?

Tags: visual-workflow

Is there a way to add a pdf document to a Flow page?
Something similar to webpages that says please read our agreement document,
And add a PDF that you can open and read,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general approach here is to [embed the Flow in a Visualforce page](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_flows_intro.htm). You can then provide a link to the PDF, outside the flow, set the PDF (or some page containing the PDF) as the Flow's `finishLocation`, or even [render dynamic content that updates as the user traverses the flow](http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2011/10/dynamic-visualforce-and-visual-workflow-with-rerender.html).

Answer (score 2):

As [metadaddy](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/67/metadaddy) mentioned:

**1.** Embed the flow in a VF Page.

```
<apex:page> 
//use the unique name of the flow   
<flow:interview name="MyUniqueFlowName"/>
</apex:page>
```

**2.** Add the logic or even pdf to that page.

```
 //Upload the pdf as a static resource 
 //Click on view file once its uploaded and copy the link
 //To this same page add a link to the pdf

 Example below:
 Read our agreement in our agreement document
  <apex:outputlink vcalue="https://na15.salesforce.com/resource/1378844344000/Test">
    here
</apex:outputlink>.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Posting a summary of somebody else's answer is not very useful. Can you provide examples or instructions to elaborate?

Comment: @MikeChale I have added the edits in my answer. Thanks for pointing it out!